# What is the meaning of this 'typedef' in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

```
typedef void (*work_func_t)(struct work_struct *work);
```

I found above typedef in Linux kernel source code, but I don't understand it. Can anyone give me some explaination? Thanks!

Complement:

```
struct work_struct {
    atomic_long_t data;
#define WORK_STRUCT_PENDING 0       /* T if work item pending execution */
#define WORK_STRUCT_STATIC  1       /* static initializer (debugobjects) */
#define WORK_STRUCT_FLAG_MASK (3UL)
#define WORK_STRUCT_WQ_DATA_MASK (~WORK_STRUCT_FLAG_MASK)
    struct list_head entry;
    work_func_t func;
#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
    struct lockdep_map lockdep_map;
#endif
};
```

From the above code which follows the "typedef", I could understand it now. @piokuc is right, thanks!

Comment: its function pointer syntax - google function pointers if you haven't come across them before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`work_func_t` is a type alias of a pointer to a function which accepts pointer to `struct work_struct` as it's only parameter and returns nothing (`void`).